# No Google Play services in SDK manager

Tags: android

There are no Google Play services in SDK manager, why and what to do?[image]

Comment: I believe these additional packages come visible after updating SDK Tools and/or Platform Tools. This happened to me at least.

Comment: You were correct, done that in the meanwhile and now it is ok. Thanks!

Comment: Yup. I updated the SDK tools and then closed and re-opened the SDK Manager and everything appeared.

Comment: I think this is because they released android wear and android tv, so you need to update sdk tools so you could get option for them...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The sdk tools needed to be updated...